# How to escape slash (/) in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, string

How do you escape the forward slash character (`/`) in VBScript? For example, in the following string:

```
bob = "VU administration/front desk"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't escape it: it doesn't mean anything special in php or vbscript, and therefore doesn't need to be escaped.  The only character you need to escape in vbscript is the double quote, which escapes itself:

```
MyString = "He said, ""Here's how you escape a double quote in vbscript. Slash characters -- both forward (/) and back (\) -- don't mean anything, even when used with common control characters like \n or \t."""
```

Similarly, in php a *backslash* escapes itself, but a forward slash doesn't need any special handling.

Answer (score 4):

This is so wrong I have to comment on it.  The question is about VBScript, not PHP, so who cares what PHP does with a slash? In VB, the forward slash **/** does have special meaning. The character **/** represents **DOUBLE**. If your code editor displays this character as **DOUBLE** or you get an error about converting to **DOUBLE** when you don't mean to convert to **DOUBLE** then you probably need to fix something in your string.

For instance, VB treats the forward slash **/** in this query string as **DOUBLE** and the program would fail here because you cant convert select *replace(convert(char(10),pih.updateon,111),* from text to double.

```
Dim sQuery As String = "select replace(convert(char(10),pih.updateon,111),"/","-") as stopdate from myTable"
```

The problem however will not likely be an issue with escaping a slash.  Chances are you goofed somewhere else.  In this case, if you typed the string correctly, it would look like this:

```
Dim sQuery As String = "select replace(convert(char(10),pih.updateon,111),'/','-') as stopdate from myTable"
```

Hope that example helps understand where you might be going wrong if you are having issues with slashes.

Addendum:  In VBScript and VB, the chief difference being VB is compiled and VBScript is interpreted, the syntax in this case is handled the same way.

d-bo

Comment: Two important syntactical differences: "Dim Var As ..." (typed declarations) are not allowed and ' introduces a comment, not a character literal. So the answer still has nothing to do with VBScript - where "/" is just a letter like "A" that can't/must not be escaped. (The upvoter(s) should think twice)

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner I did find a case where I had to "escape" "/" using Chr(47) in a hta file.

Comment: @SilentSojourner - but you found it in the HTML out of <script> blocks.

Answer (score 1):

This is very late to the discussion but I came upon this topic when researching a similar issue, when trying to match the forward slash in a standalone html tag.

From VBA documentation on the [word.find.execute method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.execute)

To search for a symbol character, type a caret (^), a zero (0), and then the symbol's character code. For example, "^0151" corresponds to an em dash (—).

From VBA documentation on the [character set code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/character-set-0127)

Forward slash "/" corresponds to 47 which you can verify with

```
Debug.Print ("Char Code 47: " & vbTab & Chr(47))
```

Match on Find using something like:

```
With Range.Find
    .MatchWildCards = True
    .Text = "\<?*.PNG^047\>"
    Do While .Execute [...]
```